# Migrate question from SO?

Tags: support, status-declined, migration

I think [this question should be migrated from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186737/124486). They've closed it and it has a TON of exp that could benefit this community.

I flagged it and RichB responded,

> This should not be closed, it should be moved to SuperUser instead. – Sep 27 at 17:29   declined - Sup, **RichB. Its a bit old for migration. You can ask on meta.super if they want it.**

Comment: It wasn't RichB who responded. The mod that handled your flag called you RichB for some bizarre reason.

Comment: Who the hell is RichB, and why would he call me that? Is he trolling? Should a mod be permitted to mask his real nick and curse me out.

Comment: You were cursed out?

Comment: He called me a RichB -- I don't even know what that is.

Comment: Possibly a mistake? Mods are humans as well...

Answer (score 10):

Migration for old posts is not possible even if we vetted it.

[Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)

> questions older than 60 days should not be eligible for migration, either by normal user close-votes or by moderators.

Answer (score 9):

The whole point is that you don't want to send tons of "exp" (it's actually "reputation") around. I don't see how it would benefit the community, really.

That, and the fact that it's really a little old.

Oh, and we [have a dupe](https://superuser.com/questions/19762) anyway.

So, there's no real point in migrating this.

Comment: So, it's closed there -- they don't want it. Better to welcome a dupe then to leave it closed. Apparently there is market for the dupe too.

Comment: Perhaps we need the ability the to merge the answers.

Comment: `Better to welcome a dupe then to leave it closed.` I don't get you here... If it's a dupe, it's going to get closed.

Comment: And then, at worst, they'll see a link to a question they can add to and improve upon: a question that is welcomed by the community. And, that's if they never fix this broken system and let us merge two questions together (like Wikipedia would do with discrete wiki pages).

Comment: @EvanCarroll No, it'd be the other way around. This one would have the link to the original one. But anyway, questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated anyway so I think this is going to be declined.

Answer (score -6):

This is a **GREAT** idea. Unfortunately, that platform doesn't have the functionality to support a migration for a question older than 60 days.

Comment: I don't see anything "great" about it... Why add another question with the same information? The wording may be different but the solution is rmdir /s /q folder on both sites.

Comment: Actually I think the SU answer is better. Also the 'functionality' was _disabled_, not really a 'support' issue here. Working as intended.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Quite frankly a plurality of questions getting migrated off of SO have been *utter crap* - the 60 day restriction was added to mitigate the effluent flow created by the new `/review` system.  If you have a constructive alternative to present we'd love to hear it, but as a mod on one of the dumping ground sites I think the restriction is a sensible one.

Comment: @Kyle that's not true, this is on the SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6208144/124486

Comment: @EvanCarroll That's also on the SU answer... http://superuser.com/a/289399/146694 Also it links to SU for "more details"

Comment: @r.tanner.f Oh, that's cool! I didn't actually read the SU answer!!!